# MySql Join condition with Where condition to get list of data

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have created the following tables -

Comment:

```
|  column   |    type     |
+-----------+-------------+
| comment_id| int(11)     |
| comment   | longText    |
| parent_id | int(11)     |
+-----------+-------------+
```

Comment Meta:

```
|  column   |    type     |
+-----------+-------------+
| comment_id| int(11)     |
| key       | varchar(40) |
| value     | varchar(50) |
+-----------+-------------+
```

with `key` value in `comment meta` table `(delete, reply_count, report)`.

Data is added to tables in the following ways:

- When a user writes a comment it is added in the `comments` database with `parent_id` set to 0.
- When a user writes a reply for a particular comment it is added in the `comments` database with `parent_id` set to `comment_id` of the comment and the `reply_count' is updated in the`comments_meta` database for that comment.
- When a user deletes a comment or a reply the value is updated in the `comments_meta` database but setting `key` to `delete` and `value` to `1` w.r.t to that comment or reply id instead of deleting it from `comments` database.

All I want is to get the list of all the comments only which are not deleted.

Till now I tried this :

`select comments.comment_id,comments.comment, ifnull(comments_meta.value,0) as reply_count from comments left join comments_meta on comments_meta.comment_id = comments.comment_id and comments_meta.meta_key = "reply_count";`

This gives me all the comments including deleted comments.

Is it possible to get a list with this table model and how?
Or I should have to attach one of property either `delete` or 'reply_count`with`comment` table?

Examples Data Comments:

```
|comment_id |    comment  |  parent_id  |  
+-----------+-------------+-------------+
|    1      | comment1    |      0      | 
|    2      | comment2    |      0      |
|    3      | reply1      |      1      |
|    4      | reply2      |      1      |
|    5      | comment3    |      0      |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+
```

Examples Data Comments Meta:

```
|comment_id |     key     |    value    |  
+-----------+-------------+-------------+
|    2      |   delete    |      1      | 
|    1      | reply_count |      2      |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+
```

Expected Output :

```
|comment_id |    comment  | reply_count |  
+-----------+-------------+-------------+
|    1      |  comment1   |      2      | 
|    5      |  comment3   |      0      |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Please provide a relevant and minimal sample data showcasing your requirements, and expected output. Ref: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: Could you explain more detail on your question? I am not sure what's the logic between those tables

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I edited the questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DDL:

```
create table `comment`(
  `comment_id` int not null auto_increment,
  `comment` varchar(128),
  `parent_id` int not null,
  primary key(`comment_id`)
);


insert into `comment`(`comment_id`,`comment`,`parent_id`) values
(1,'comment1',0),
(2,'comment2',0),
(3,'reply1',1),
(4,'reply2',1),
(5,'comment3',0);

create table `comment_meta`(
  `comment_id` int not null,
  `key` varchar(128),
  `value` int not null,
  primary key(`comment_id`,`key`)
);

insert into `comment_meta`(`comment_id`,`key`,`value`) values
(2,'delete',1),
(1,'reply_count',2);
```

Let's get just the "root" comments:

```
  SELECT * FROM `comment` 
  WHERE `parent_id` = 0
```

Let's select only comments:

```
  SELECT * FROM `comment` 
  WHERE `parent_id` != 0
```

Let's join (outer - to list all the root comments) these two subqueries and see what we get:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT * FROM `comment` 
  WHERE `parent_id` = 0
) AS `root_comments`
LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT * FROM `comment` 
  WHERE `parent_id` != 0  
) `replies` ON `replies`.`parent_id` = `root_comments`.`comment_id`;
```

We get something like [this](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6yh9tqKtzMTTBTaoYGRc1e/0) :
[image]

Now let's add one additional column to our resultset showing if this row represents a root comment (0) or a reply (1):

```
SELECT *,IF(`replies`.`comment_id` IS NOT NULL, 1, 0)
FROM
(
  SELECT * FROM `comment` 
  WHERE `parent_id` = 0
) AS `root_comments`
LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT * FROM `comment` 
  WHERE `parent_id` != 0  
) `replies` ON `replies`.`parent_id` = `root_comments`.`comment_id`;
```

Let's select deleted comments:

```
SELECT * FROM `comment_meta`
WHERE `key` = 'delete'
```

join them with what we have at the moment and add a `WHERE` condition to consider only those comments, which do not have corresponding row with 'delete' key in meta table:

```
WHERE `deleted_comments`.`comment_id` IS NULL
```

Finally we need to select only the needed columns and `GROUP BY` comment/`SUM()` the replies (1) for each comment up:

Beware that in MySQL 5.7 the `GROUP BY` default mode has been changed and you cannot `SUM` non-grouped columns without changing this setting.

```
SELECT `root_comments`.`comment_id`,`root_comments`.`comment`,SUM(IF(`replies`.`comment_id` IS NOT NULL, 1, 0)) AS reply_count
FROM
(
  SELECT * FROM `comment` 
  WHERE `parent_id` = 0
) AS `root_comments`
LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT * FROM `comment` 
  WHERE `parent_id` != 0  
) `replies` ON `replies`.`parent_id` = `root_comments`.`comment_id`
LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT * FROM `comment_meta`
  WHERE `key` = 'delete'
) `deleted_comments` ON `deleted_comments`.`comment_id` = `root_comments`.`comment_id`
WHERE `deleted_comments`.`comment_id` IS NULL
GROUP BY `root_comments`.`comment_id`;
```

Here is the [link](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jVL7yDNAozgyWvkQnwuzsh/2) to the DBFiddle with this working example